# implementing onclicklistener is not working?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, onclicklistener

I'm trying to implement onclicklistener but it isn't working on my phone or emulator.

here is the code:

```
package com.slaps.guess;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
TextView tv;
Button one;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    one = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvd);     
}
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button1:
        tv.setText("Anything");
        break;
    }

}
}
```

the text view is not changing to anything it is still.

note: button1 exists, and their is nothing wrong with my xml.
i want to implement because i have alot of button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing one.setOnClickListener(this) in your code.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    one = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    one.setOnClickListener(this);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvd);     
}
```

Comment: i love you man thx alot.     but the one.setOn should be below the tv

Answer (score 0):

Before using listener you will have to add it in the object for which you want it.
I guess you want for the Button `one` here.

Use `one.setOnClickListener(this)` after `one = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing the required XML attribute in `res/layout/activity_main.xml`. Ensure it looks like:

```
<Button
  android:id="@+id/button1"
  onClick="onClick"
/>
```

The key being you have supplied the `onClick` attribute with the name of your method to invoke.

But if you want to set the click listener programmatically than you will need to use the `Button.setOnClickListener` method. If you do this your method signature will need to change to:

```
one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Perform action on click   
                }
            });
```